# No data parsed on the first appended d3 element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new in D3.js and have this simple code, [See jsbin output here](https://jsbin.com/haxule/2)

```
var data = [
  {country: 'Kenya', performance_rate: 5},
  {country: 'Uganda', performance_rate: 5},
  {country: 'Rwanda', performance_rate: 2},
  {country: 'S.Sudan', performance_rate: 1}
];

var chartBody = d3.select('body').append('h1').text('Progress by country');

var chart = d3.selectAll('p');

chart.data(data).enter().append('span')
 .classed('bar',true).style('width', function(d){
   rate = (d.performance_rate *100)/5;
   return rate+'%';}).text(function(d){
   return d.country;
});
```

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart from the dataset. My problem is, the first item in the dataset i.e `{ country: Kenya, performance_rate: 5}` is not passed in the output.

How can I make sure all my data set items are rendered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your html, you already have one p element and so when you do  `d3.selectAll('p');` it returns that one existing element.

> **selection.enter()**
>
> Returns the enter selection: placeholder nodes for each data element
>   for which **no** corresponding existing DOM element was found in the
>   current selection.

Therefore remove the p element from html and try as shown below.

```
var chart = d3.select('body').append('p').selectAll("span");
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
var data = [
  {country: 'Kenya', performance_rate: 5},
    {country: 'Uganda', performance_rate: 5},
    {country: 'Rwanda', performance_rate: 2},
    {country: 'S.Sudan', performance_rate: 1}
];
var chartBody = d3.select('body').append('h1').text('Progress by country');

var chart = d3.select('body').append('p').selectAll("span");

chart.data(data).enter().append('span').classed('bar', true).style('width', function(d){
  rate = (d.performance_rate *100)/5;
  return rate+'%';
}).text(function(d){
  return d.country;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="D3 bar chart learning">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .bar {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 21px;
      padding: 10px;
      color: black;
      display:block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gilsha. I have seen what you did there. Works great.

Comment: A different thing, though, how have you appended the above code and I'm able to run it. I mean the ">Run code snippet" and the other buttons at the bottom. I would like to do something like that in future. What's the tool?Thanks once again.

Comment: Click the 7th button in the toolbar - Javascript/HTML/CSS Snippet button. Or just press `Ctrl+M`